# Tcolorbox label and cross-reference autocomplete

Tags: pdftex, tcolorbox, labels, overleaf

I am using `tcolorbox` package for making environment.

I use the method that is shown on page 355 in [the manual](https://mirror-hk.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) (17.1  Macros of the Library): `\newtcbtheorem`.

May I ask if there is anyway to make a label provided by `\newtcbtheorem` be a suggestion in auto-complete feature on OverLeaf?

Labels of equations, figures or other environment based on `\newtheorem` provided by `amsthm` package can be easily found using auto-complete feature like this:

[image]

However, when using `\newtcbtheorem` with default label `<prefix>:<marker>`, it won't show up in the auto-complete field. For example, if I created a new environment with the following parameters:

```
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=chapter]{test}{Test environment}{enhanced,
  breakable,colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{ts}
```

The auto-complete feature shows nothing as I type the label (the complete label here is `ts:inverse` acording to the syntax):

[image]

Comment: Hi! Tom from Overleaf Support here. I'm afraid we can't parse for labels that are not created the standard way using \label{...}, sorry for the limitation.

Comment: Thank you for your support. It's quite sad to hear that. I hope this feature will considered in the future.